# How to set an ImageView and two TextviewS to have the same height?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I've got the following layout with one ImageView and 2 TextView, I would like them all to have the same height. However, the ImageView is always taking more than half of the screen. Any help is highly apreciated.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:src="@drawable/sprint" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:background="#555555"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the dimension of the image?

Comment: Do you want the textviews to have the same height or all three to have the same height?

Comment: @Win Myo Htet The image is 753 px height * 401 px width

Comment: @Squazic I want all three views to have the same height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to Set

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" and android:layout_weight="1"
```

Following is the Link Which might Help You. [LINK](http://joseluisugia.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/)

Comment: Thanks your link helped me a lot. The trick was to set  android:layout_weight="1" and android:layout_height="0dp"

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for all three, make sure that your image dimension is not bigger than you defined for its alloted space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this few minor changes...

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/sprinklicious" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#555555"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in image view change src to background and try